# JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 43 (char 42)

Tags: python

I have read on many examples here already on SO. Unfortunately, I keep getting this error,

**Error:**

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 43 (char 42)
```

**json file:**

```
{"people": [{"name": "Scott", "from": "Nebraska", "website": "stackabuse.com"}, {"name": "Larry", "from": "Michigan", "website": "google.com"}, {"name": "Tim", "from": "Alabama", "website": "apple.com"}]}
```

**And another separate json file:**

```
{"scores":[{"name":"Larry","result":["0":"24","1":"43","2":"56"]},{"name":"Tim","result":["0":"44","1":"29","2":"34"]}]}
```

**python code:**

```
with open('data.json') as file:
          data = json.load(file)

    print(data)
```

Comment: your first json file does not have any issues and printed data. as mentioned in the answers, it is the second file (seperate json file) having a list but provided dict type values.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid, it has `:` tokens in an array:

```
"result": ["0": "24", "1": "43", "2": "56"]
#             ^          ^          ^
```

and

```
"result": ["0": "44", "1": "29", "2": "34"]
#             ^          ^          ^
```

Fix your JSON input; either replace those colons with commas, remove the `"0":`, `"1":`, and `"2":` 'indices', or replace the `[...]` array brackets with `{...}` JSON object braces.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a JSON, list or dict - not a python valid type:

```
["0":"24","1":"43","2":"56"]
```

in order to fix this and continue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the JSON file was valid. However, I did this,

```
with open('json_file.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(json_data,f)

    # an api request that does that
    # with open('json_file.json', r) as w:
    #    json.load(w)
    response = requests.post(...)
```

I tried to read the file before it was actually written. Moving the api request outside the `with` statement solved the issue.