# Extracting keys from dataframe of json

Tags: python, json, pandas, key, extract

I'm sorry, I am new to Python and wondering if anyone can help me with extracting data? I've been trying to extract data from a df with json-content.

```
0    [{'@context': 'https://schema.org', '@type': '...
1    [{'@context': 'https://schema.org', '@type': '...
2    [{'@context': 'https://schema.org', '@type': '...
3    [{'@context': 'https://schema.org', '@type': '...
4    [{'@context': 'https://schema.org', '@type': '...
5    [{'@context': 'https://schema.org', '@type': '...
```

So rows look like this:

```
"[{'@context': 'https://schema.org', '@type': 'Audiobook', 'bookFormat': 'AudiobookFormat', 'name': 'Balle-Lars og mordet i Ugledige 1858', 'description': '<p>I 1858 blev der begået et mord i Ugledige mellem Præstø og Vordingborg. Den 58-årige enke Ane Marie Hemmingsdatter blev skudt.</p><p>Lars Peter Poulsen (1866-1941) var en dansk lærer og forfatter.</p>', 'image': '/images/e/200x200/0002496352.jpg', 'author': [{'@type': 'Person', 'name': 'L.P. Poulsen'}], 'readBy': [], 'publisher': {'@type:': 'Organization', 'name': ''}, 'isbn': '', 'datePublished': '', 'inLanguage': 'da', 'aggregateRating': {'@type': 'AggregateRating', 'ratingValue': 3.56, 'ratingCount': 9}}, {'@context': 'https://schema.org', '@type': 'Book', 'bookFormat': 'EBook', 'name': 'Balle-Lars og mordet i Ugledige 1858', 'description': '<p>I 1858 blev der begået et mord i Ugledige mellem Præstø og Vordingborg. Den 58-årige enke Ane Marie Hemmingsdatter blev skudt.</p>', 'image': '/images/e/200x200/0002496352.jpg', 'author': [{'@type': 'Person', 'name': 'L.P. Poulsen'}], 'publisher': {'@type:': 'Organization', 'name': 'SAGA Egmont'}, 'isbn': '9788726519877', 'datePublished': '2021-06-21', 'inLanguage': 'da', 'aggregateRating': {'@type': 'AggregateRating', 'ratingValue': 3.56, 'ratingCount': 9}}]"
```

What I want is to get some of the keys (e.g. 'name') from the json data, for all rows.
I've been trying:

```
for d in unsorted:
    print (d["name"])
```

... and variations. Is that the way to go (somehow) or should I convert everything to json and go from there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the dataframe looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'json_data': ['[{"@context": "https://schema.org", "@type": "Audiobook", "bookFormat": "AudiobookFormat", "name": "Balle-Lars og mordet i Ugledige 1858", "description": "<p>I 1858 blev der begået et mord i Ugledige mellem Præstø og Vordingborg. Den 58-årige enke Ane Marie Hemmingsdatter blev skudt, da hun stod ved vinduet i sin stue efter at være kommet hjem fra et begravelsesg."}]',
                                    '[{"@context": "https://schema.org", "@type": "Audiobook", "bookFormat": "AudiobookFormat", "name": "Balle-Lars og mordet i Ugledige 1858", "description": "<p>I 1858 blev der begået et mord i Ugledige mellem Præstø og Vordingborg. Den 58-årige enke Ane Marie Hemmingsdatter blev skudt, da hun stod ved vinduet i sin stue efter at være kommet hjem fra et begravelsesg."}]',
                                    '[{"@context": "https://schema.org", "@type": "Audiobook", "bookFormat": "AudiobookFormat", "name": "Balle-Lars og mordet i Ugledige 1858", "description": "<p>I 1858 blev der begået et mord i Ugledige mellem Præstø og Vordingborg. Den 58-årige enke Ane Marie Hemmingsdatter blev skudt, da hun stod ved vinduet i sin stue efter at være kommet hjem fra et begravelsesg."}]',
                                    '[{"@context": "https://schema.org", "@type": "Audiobook", "bookFormat": "AudiobookFormat", "name": "Balle-Lars og mordet i Ugledige 1858", "description": "<p>I 1858 blev der begået et mord i Ugledige mellem Præstø og Vordingborg. Den 58-årige enke Ane Marie Hemmingsdatter blev skudt, da hun stod ved vinduet i sin stue efter at være kommet hjem fra et begravelsesg."}]',
                                    '[{"@context": "https://schema.org", "@type": "Audiobook", "bookFormat": "AudiobookFormat", "name": "Balle-Lars og mordet i Ugledige 1858", "description": "<p>I 1858 blev der begået et mord i Ugledige mellem Præstø og Vordingborg. Den 58-årige enke Ane Marie Hemmingsdatter blev skudt, da hun stod ved vinduet i sin stue efter at være kommet hjem fra et begravelsesg."}]'] })

[Out]:
                                           json_data
0  [{"@context": "https://schema.org", "@type": "...
1  [{"@context": "https://schema.org", "@type": "...
2  [{"@context": "https://schema.org", "@type": "...
3  [{"@context": "https://schema.org", "@type": "...
4  [{"@context": "https://schema.org", "@type": "...
```

And assuming that OP's goal is just to obtain a list with the names, one can get it as follows

```
import json as js

name_list = [js.loads(x)[0]['name'] for x in df['json_data'].tolist()]

[Out]:

['Balle-Lars og mordet i Ugledige 1858', 'Balle-Lars og mordet i Ugledige 1858', 'Balle-Lars og mordet i Ugledige 1858', 'Balle-Lars og mordet i Ugledige 1858', 'Balle-Lars og mordet i Ugledige 1858']
```

If OP wants to store the names on a different column, called `name`, of the dataframe `df`, then one can do the following

```
import json as js

df['name'] = [js.loads(x)[0]['name'] for x in df['json_data'].tolist()]

    [Out]:
json_data                                  name
0  [{"@context": "https://schema.org", "@type": "...  Balle-Lars og mordet i Ugledige 1858
1  [{"@context": "https://schema.org", "@type": "...  Balle-Lars og mordet i Ugledige 1858
2  [{"@context": "https://schema.org", "@type": "...  Balle-Lars og mordet i Ugledige 1858
3  [{"@context": "https://schema.org", "@type": "...  Balle-Lars og mordet i Ugledige 1858
4  [{"@context": "https://schema.org", "@type": "...  Balle-Lars og mordet i Ugledige 1858
```

Comment: Thanks Gonçalo! Looks good, though I'm getting `JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 113 (char 112)` - something not well prepared in there?

Comment: @PascaleFM that could indicate that the JSON is invalid. There are various SO Q&A on that error: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41262180/7109869), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736000/python-jsondecodeerror-expecting-delimiter), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9156417/7109869).